# UI-Router not changing state when using $state.go()

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine, angular-ui-router

I am writing a unit test for my *ui-router* routes. However, I cannot make it pass.

Here's my test, and the `$state.current.name` is giving me `frontpage` which is the `otherwise` state.

```
it('should change state to items', function() {
    $state.go('items');

    $rootScope.$digest();

    expect($state.current.name).toBe('items');
})
```

The state:

```
$urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/");

$stateProvider
    .state('items', {
        url: '/items',
        templateUrl: 'js/modules/items/partials/items.html',
        controller: 'ItemsController',

        resolve: {
            items : ['ItemService', '$q', function(ItemService, $q) {

                var defer = $q.defer();

                ItemService.getItems().success(function(data) {

                    defer.resolve(data);

                });

                return defer.promise;
            }]
        }

    })

    .state('frontpage', {
        url: '/',
        template: 'Frontpage'
    })
```

Why am I getting the `frontpage` state after calling `$state.go('items')`?

Answer (score 0):

Inject $q, then try $q.flush(); after changing state.

Answer (score 0):

After spending couple of hours, I ended up using `$timeout.flush()`, I guess which is clearing out all the promise queue.